# cannot import name 'Datetime' python flask sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, datetime, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run a Flask - SQLAlchemy application. What I want to do is add the creation datetime by default at each insert in my table **usuario**. So far, I have 2 files:

Here, I create Usuario class to create users with some information and add the datetime as a default value.

**database_setup.py**

```
import datetime
import os
import sys
# in the next line, i get the error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Datetime'
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Datetime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base=declarative_base()


class Usuario(Base):
    __tablename__='usuario'

    id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    usuario_id=Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    password=Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    email=Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    nombres=Column(String(300), nullable=False)
    apellidos=Column(String(300), nullable=False)
    # Here, I want to set a default value for each user
    fecha_creacion=Column(Datetime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

# String connection to mysql database
engine=create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost/bdname')


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

The problem comes here, when I try to run this file from the console:

> python3 project.py

I got the next lines:

> File "project.py", line 4, in  
>       from database_setup import Base, Usuario
>   File "/home/facturacion/compartido/Cambio/database_setup.py", line 4, in 
>       from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Datetime
>   importError: cannot import name 'Datetime'

**project.py**

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, request, redirect, jsonify, url_for, session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Base, Usuario
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

engine = create_engine('mysql://root:facturacion@localhost/cambio')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
dbsession = DBSession()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return 'Logged in as %s' % session['username']
    return 'Aun no se encuentra logueado'

@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usuario_frompost = request.form['username']
        pass_frompost = request.form['password']
        user = None
        if '@' in usuario_frompost:
            user = dbsession.query(Usuario).filter_by(email = usuario_frompost, password = pass_frompost)
        else:
            user = dbsession.query(Usuario).filter_by(usuario_id = usuario_frompost, password = pass_frompost)

        if user:
            flash('Login exitoso')
            session['username'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return '''
        <form method="post">
            <p><input type=text name=username>
            <p><input type=password name=password>
            <p><input type=submit value=Login>
        </form>
    '''

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple, just a typo:

```
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
```

**DateTime** not **Datetime**

Comment: Thank you for your help. You were right. But after I made the correction, it throw the error **No module named 'MySQLdb'**. I installed pip3 install mysqlclient and works like a charm!

Comment: To avoid these very easy to make typos, i'll often just `import sqlalchemy`

and reference everything through `sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Datetime)` etc. To save typing you can do `import sqlalchemy as sqla`. Not sure if there is a community standard for abbreviation.